# JQuery Ajax + Waypoints don't work

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-waypoints

I use wordpress+timber+twig and I have the following issue. I 've loaded 9 first images on the screen, and after I scroll down it needs to show 10 more images, etc. I have a correct function in functions.php, since it always outputs the right 10 images I need. But I cannot define the correct jQuery function in the .twig file. I am trying to use waypoints, but it outputs an error: "Uncaught Error: No element option passed to Waypoint constructor". As I understand, it happens, because not all the DOM tree is loaded and the browser doesn't see the needed nodes for the waypoints. Now it output the right images, but at the same time - not 10 after 10. How can I load the block of divs and bind the waypoint to the last div, so that it could be seen by the browser? Or maybe there is much more simple way out? Here is my unideal code. :) Thank you in advance!

```
   jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
                var ajaxUrl = "{{ fn('admin_url', 'admin-ajax.php') }}";

                function add_posts(img_link, key) {
                    $(".gallery-ajax").append(
                        '<div class="img-container" id="img-container' + key + '">' +
                        '<a data-fancybox="gallery" id="image' + key + '" href="' + img_link + '">' +
                        '<img src="' + img_link + '">' +
                        '</a>' +
                        '</div>'
                    );
                }

                function ajax_call(page, ppp) {
                    $.post(ajaxUrl, {
                        action: "more_post_ajax",
                        page: page,
                        ppp: ppp

                    }).success(function (data) {


                        $.each(data, function (key, val) {
                            add_posts(val.img_link, val.skaitliukas);
                            console.log(val);
                            Waypoint.refreshAll();
                        });

                        if (page + 1 < len) {

                            page = page + ppp;

                            waypoint = new Waypoint({
                                element: document.getElementById("img-container" + page),
                                handler: ajax_call(page, ppp),
                                offset: 'bottom-in-view'
                            });

                        }
                    })
                }

                // The index of the last image loaded.
                {% if post.gallery | length >=9 %}
                var page = 8;
                {% else %}
                var page = 10;
                {% endif %}

                // Post per page
                var ppp = 10;

                var len = {{ post.gallery | length }};
                var waypoints = [];
                var waypoint;

                waypoint = new Waypoint({
                    element: document.getElementById('img-container' + page),
                    handler: function () {
                        console.log("Page equals " + page);

                        jQuery.post(ajaxUrl, {
                            action: "more_post_ajax",
                            page: page,
                            ppp: ppp

                        }).success(function (data) {


                            jQuery.each(data, function (key, val) {
                                add_posts(val.img_link, val.skaitliukas);
                                console.log(val);
                                Waypoint.refreshAll();
                            });

                            page = page + ppp;

                            waypoint = new Waypoint({
                                element: document.getElementById("img-container" + page),
                                handler: ajax_call(page, ppp),
                                offset: 'bottom-in-view'
                            });


                        });

                    },
                    offset: 'bottom-in-view'
                });

            });
```

Answer (score 0):

I actually solved my own problem through defining only one waypoint at the end of the page. When the waypoint is reached, it is moved 5 images further, so the waypoint can load again and again. Here is my code:

```
            jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
                var ajaxUrl = "{{ fn('admin_url', 'admin-ajax.php') }}";

                function add_posts(img_link, key) {
                    $(".gallery-ajax").append(
                        '<div class="img-container" id="img-container' + key + '">' +
                        '<a data-fancybox="gallery" id="image' + key + '" href="' + img_link + '">' +
                        '<div class="img-small3">' +
                        '<img class="img-responsive" src="' + img_link + '">' +
                        '<div class="arrow-hover"></div>' +
                        '</div>' +
                        '</a>' +
                        '</div>'
                    );
                }

                // The index of the last image loaded.
                {% if post.gallery | length >=9 %}
                var page = 8;


                // Post per page
                var ppp = 5;

                var len = {{ post.gallery | length }};

                var waypoint;


                waypoint = new Waypoint({
                    element: document.getElementById("ajax-line"),
                    handler: function () {
                        if (page < len) {
                            jQuery(".loader-wrap").fadeIn();
                            jQuery.post(ajaxUrl, {
                                action: "more_post_ajax",
                                page: page,
                                ppp: ppp

                            }).success(function (data) {


                                jQuery.each(data, function (key, val) {
                                    add_posts(val.img_link, val.skaitliukas);

                                });
                                page = page + ppp;
                                Waypoint.refreshAll();
                                jQuery(".loader-wrap").fadeOut();

                            });
                        }
                    },
                    offset: 'bottom-in-view'
                });



                {% endif %}
            });
```